# Extract variables with preg match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi i am having an issue in trying to extract variables using preg replace .I guess i am messing with the delimiters or just doing it wrong

Subject

```
'file': 'EoWviKqVizQ,end=1384596943/data=B262F941/speed=375k/2305873_hd.flv',
```

I need to extract

```
end=1384596943/data=B262F941/speed=375k/1234_hd.flv
```

This is basically the string after the comma in between the single quotes.

My attempts

```
preg_match('#'file':'(.*)'#',$input , $matches)

preg_match("#'file':'(.*)'#",$input , $matches)
```

Hope someone can help me out

Regards

Comment: What would help is posting your code which isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$input = "'file': 'EoWviKqVizQ,end=1384596943/data=B262F941/speed=375k/2305873_hd.flv',";
$mypart = preg_replace("/^'file': '[^,]+,/", "", $input); // strip first part, i.e., "'file': 'EoWviKqVizQ,"
$mypart = preg_replace("/',\s*$/", "", $mypart); // strip last part, i.e., "',"
echo $mypart;
```

**EDITED** based on OP feedback (replaced initial `[^']+` with `file` to match only lines starting with `'file'`, etc.

Comment: Kindly point out what do you mean by first part and last part

Comment: Well, in your example, the "first part" would be `'file': 'EoWviKqVizQ,`, and the "last part" would be the trailing `',`.

Comment: Its gr8 dude but can you please modify the code .There are multiple lines like this and i need only the one with 'file', not every ''